# How can I change default active item of Bottom Navigation in kivymd?

Tags: python, navigation, kivy, kivymd

I am a beginner in kivymd. I was trying to create bottom-navigation in kivymd. After run the code the it showing active item of Bottom Navigation is 'Home'(name='screen_1). Now I want second item as default active item -> 'Features'(name='screen_2'). This is sample code.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size=(350,593)

KV_string = """ 
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title:'Demo Application'
            right_action_items : [["dots-vertical"]]
            left_action_items : [["menu", lambda x: app.menu_toggle()]]
            right_action_items : [["dots-vertical", lambda x: app.option_fun()]]
            elevation:10
            
        MDLabel:
            text:'Welcome to good GUI'
            halign:'center'

        MDBottomNavigation: 
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen_1'
                text: 'Home'
                icon: 'home-outline'
                on_tab_press: app.Bottom_nav_fun()

                MDLabel:
                    text: 'Home page'
                    halign: 'center'

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen_2'
                text: 'Features'
                icon: 'feature-search-outline'

                MDLabel:
                    text: 'Features of this app'
                    halign: 'center'

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen_3'
                text: 'Developers'
                icon: 'account-supervisor'

                MDLabel:
                    text: 'Developers details'
                    halign: 'center'
"""


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette="Blue"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style="Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue="A700"
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV_string)
        return self.screen
    def menu_toggle(self):
        print("Menu toggle Working")
    def option_fun(self):
        print("Option method Working")
    def Bottom_nav_fun(self):
        print("Bottom nav home")

if __name__=='__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: Do you need to have it as default but always in the center of the bottom toolbar? Or do you need it as default but at the left of the bottom toolbar?

Comment: - I need any one of them as default, whenever I want. For example in some page I need it as default but at the left of the bottom toolbar, in other page as default but always in the center of the bottom toolbar.

Comment: Alright, the side bottom icons should move to the center of the bottom bar when they are pressed right?, always at the center because the icon has been clicked, it is possible, by switching the label text and the icon and moving it to the center, I will try to do it

Answer (score 0):

Use method switch_tab which takes as argument the name of the tab you want to switch to -  https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/bottomnavigation/#how-to-automatically-switch-a-tab

Answer (score -1):

here is method how change Tab in kivymd

kv file:

```
MDBottomNavigation:
    id:btm_tab
```

py file:

self.ids.btm_tab.switch_tab(name_tab)